# Is it possible to access an entire picture's color in Flash?

Tags: image, actionscript-3, flash

I'm trying to change the brightness of an image in Flash. I have converted the flash to a bitmap, and would like to make a button that increases or decreases the brightness of the image as a whole. Is there a way to access every pixel in the image at once to do this (using code, not the Panels on Stage)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `ColorMatrixFilter` class, you can adjust the brightness by applying the same multiplier to each color channel.

So something like this (from this [source](http://chargedweb.com/labs/2010/04/30/fast_brightness_contrast_saturation/)):

```
    image.filters = [makeBrightFilter(50)];

    function makeBrightFilter(amount):ColorMatrixFilter {
        amount = amount * (255/250);
        var m:Array = new Array();
        m = m.concat([1, 0, 0, 0, amount]);  // red
        m = m.concat([0, 1, 0, 0, amount]);  // green
        m = m.concat([0, 0, 1, 0, amount]);  // blue
        m = m.concat([0, 0, 0, 1, 0]);      // alpha

        return new ColorMatrixFilter(m);
    }
```

To abstract it out and make it even easier, you could use a library like [Grant Skinner's ColorMatrix class](http://blog.gskinner.com/archives/2007/12/colormatrix_cla.html).

Then you do something like this:

```
import com.gskinner.geom.ColorMatrix;
import flash.filters.ColorMatrixFilter;

var matrix:ColorMatrix = new ColorMatrix();
matrix.adjustBrightness(50);
image.filters = [new ColorMatrixFilter(matrix)];
```